# XSLT is not compiling due to Internal Server Error

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 and I am trying to check it's for well formedness.

my XSLT is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <div style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
         <xsl:if test="//PQMessage[.!='']">
            <div>
               <img align="absmiddle" src="contactImages/messageBox/exclamationICON.gif" />
               <b>
                  <xsl:value-of select="//PQMessage" />
               </b>
            </div>
         </xsl:if>
         <div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 10px; height: 220px; color2: #590a18; background-image: url( contactImages/claimLineInfobox.gif );background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <img src="contactImages/divisionsCenter.gif" style="position: relative; left: 14px; top: 4px; " alt="dividerbar" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//divisions" />
         </div>
         <div id="BrokerListResults" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 20px; width: 960px; height: 400px; color2: #590a18; background-image: url( contactImages/listofDivisionBrokersbox.gif );background-repeat: no-repeat;" />
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="divisions">
      <xsl:variable name="userProvidedEffDate" select="number(concat(substring(//userProvidedEffDate, 7, 4), substring(//userProvidedEffDate, 1, 2), substring(//userProvidedEffDate, 4, 2)))" />
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="division" />
      </xsl:copy>
      <div id="divisionsListAA" style="position:relative; top:0px; left:10px; width:907px;">
         <table id="DivisionTableHead" class="PQTable" border="0" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="position:relative; width:890px; font-size:11pt;">
            <tr style=" position:relative; background-color:#FAF6F2; font-weight:bold;">
               <td width="50px" />
               <td style=" width:162px; ">Division #</td>
               <td style=" width:162px; ">Effective Date</td>
               <td style=" width:162px; ">Expiration Date</td>
               <td style=" width:112px; ">Business Unit</td>
               <td style=" width:81px; ">Program</td>
               <td style=" width:81px; ">Carrier</td>
               <td style=" width:81px; ">Region</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <table id="DivisionTable" class="PQTable stripeRow" border="0" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="position:relative; width:890px; font-size:11pt;">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="division" />
         </table>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="division">
      <xsl:if test="([number(concat(substring(GroupEffDt, 7, 4), substring(GroupEffDt, 1, 2), substring(GroupEffDt, 4, 2))) &lt;= $userProvidedEffDate                                       and number(concat(substring(GroupExpDt, 7, 4), substring(GroupExpDt, 1, 2), substring(GroupExpDt, 4, 2))) &gt;= $userProvidedEffDate])">
         <tr>
            <td width="50px">
               <div onclick="resetAmisysDivisionDisplay(this);">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                  <div id="DivisionDetailArea" style="display: none;" />
               </div>
            </td>
            <td width="162px">
               <xsl:value-of select="GroupNumber" />
            </td>
            <td width="162px">
               <xsl:value-of select="GroupEffDt" />
            </td>
            <td width="162px">
               <xsl:value-of select="GroupExpDt" />
            </td>
            <td width="112px">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(groupLOB,1,2)" />
            </td>
            <td width="81px">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(groupLOB,4,2)" />
            </td>
            <td width="81px">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(groupLOB,7,2)" />
            </td>
            <td width="81px">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring(groupLOB,10,2)" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to compile the above xsl online(http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XPEFsogza71), I am getting the below error:

```
Internal Server Error: <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Server Error</body></html>
```

It appears that the XSL file not well formed one. I am unable to figure out the actual problem.

What could be the mistake here? Could you please help me?

Comment: You need to use a better tool for debugging your XSLT. One that reports the error. Try this... http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZD

Comment: @Tim C, Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the website is not getting opened at my work location, may be blacklisted(not sure why they have done so). Any other website that you can suggest please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should get a tool that provides detailed error reports rather than rely on other people debugging your code.

As it happens, you have at least two errors on line 44:

```
<xsl:if test="([number(concat(substring(GroupEffDt, 7, 4), substring(GroupEffDt, 1, 2), substring(GroupEffDt, 4, 2))) &lt;= $userProvidedEffDate                                       and number(concat(substring(GroupExpDt, 7, 4), substring(GroupExpDt, 1, 2), substring(GroupExpDt, 4, 2))) &gt;= $userProvidedEffDate])">
```

1. the variable `userProvidedEffDate` has not been defined;
2. the expression is invalid because of your use of square brackets.

Neither of these has anything to do with your XSLT being well-formed.

Comment: Michael was very generous to provide an answer here.  Compilation errors are generally off-topic on this site; there's even a specific close reason covering typos and such issues that are unlikely to be useful to future readers.  There is no way you'll be able to develop XSLT without use of a tool that will provide you directly with such error messages.  I suggest that you look into Saxon's free offerings to get started and consider their paid products if you're doing professional development.

Comment: @michael.hor257k,  I am applying the solution proposed as part of the question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354583/finding-whether-a-date-falls-within-the-date-range-using-xslt/56356258#56356258) slightly in a different way. I will declare the variable globally as per your suggestion, but what is the alternative for the square brackets?  It would be great if you can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Square brackets are used to add a predicate to a node test. They are not needed here and you do not need an alternative for them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thanks for your explanation. Plus one for your helping attitude.